# How to properly convert new Date(0L) to LocalDate (1970-01-01)?

Tags: java, java-time, localdate

Consider code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

/**
 * @author nsheremet
 */
public class MyTest {
    private static final Date CREATED_ON = new Date(0L);

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        LocalDate actualDate = CREATED_ON.toInstant()
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .toLocalDate();
        assertThat(actualDate).isEqualTo(LocalDate.of(1970, 01, 01));
    }
}
```

On my machine it works good but on other I got en exception:

```
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR] MyTest.someTest:23 expected: <19[70-01-0]1> but was:<19[69-12-3]>1
```

Why it happens? Using `UTC` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is corrent?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference in type between a `Date` (an instant on the timeline) and a `LocalDate` (a notionally 24 hour-long period, in some specific time zone). You can *only* convert with reference to a particular time zone.

Comment: @smac89 "I believe the farthest back a LocalDate can extend is Epoch" [you believe wrongly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN).

Comment: `LocalDate.EPOCH`?

Comment: It’s one of the problems with `Date`, despite the class name it defines a point in time, and at that point in time there will always be different dates in different time zones.

Comment: At epoch, the date was 1970-1-1 or 1969-12-31 depending on your time zone. Using UTC, GMT+0 up to GMT+12 happens to work in this case, however, if the `Date` is not at midnight for GMT+0, your choice of timezone can still make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

> Why it happens? Using UTC instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is
>   correct?

Yes. EPOCH for `java.util.Date` is **January 1st, 1970 00:00:00.000 UTC**, But `ZoneId.systemDefault()` will fetch what the current computer is configured to use as user time zone. Which is extremely unlikely to be UTC.

So you need to use time zone UTC, rather than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.ofEpochMilli( 0L ) 
.atOffset( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC
)
.toLocalDate()
.toString()
```

> 1970-01-01

## `java.util.Date`

`java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, a date with a time-of-day.

Your code:

```
new Date(0L)
```

…produced an object representing the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

## Time zone

At that same moment, asking someone on the phone in India to tell you the time-of-day they see on the clock would get you an answer of “5:30 AM”. The time zone `Asia/Kolkata` at that moment used an offset of five and a half hours *ahead* of UTC.

If on the phone with someone in Montréal Québec, you would get the answer of “7 PM… of the date 1969-12-31”. The time zone `America/Montreal` on that date used an offset of five hours *behind* UTC. Being hours behind midnight in UTC means being on the date behind too, the last day of 1969 rather than the first day of 1970. Ditto for the zone `America/New_York` and much of the east coast of North America.

So, you must understand that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe, the date varies by zone. When a new day dawns in Japan, it is still “yesterday” in Brazil, for example.

## java.time

The `Date` class is terrible, and should **never be used**. Along with `Calendar` it is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, `Date` is replaced by `Instant`, both classes representing a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 0L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00Z

Adjust into the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion, without the time-of-day and without the zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1969-12-31

If you want to stay in UTC, apply a `ZoneOffset` constant of `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of a `ZoneId`. And get an `OffsetDateTime` rather than a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract the date-only value, a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1970-01-01

Answer (score 1):

The possible problem is that your both machines are in different time zones.
Check the ZoneId on both machines (if they are the same).

Maybe you want to put defined ZoneId, to ensure that results will always be the same?

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you have phrased it as a comment. Please reword and expand it.

Comment: This is not at all a matter of different time zones between different machines, actually. A java.util.Date uses UTC when built from a delta from Epoch. The machine's preferences are not involved.